# Swift: UIButton Customization

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, function, uibutton

I would like to move the code to customize `UIButtons` out of my `viewcontroller` classes as a best practice.  The code I have below is to add a white border to `UIButtons` and I would like to easily call it on buttons throughout my project.

```
    //White Border
    let passwordBorder = CALayer()

    let width = CGFloat(5.0)

    passwordBorder.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

    passwordBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:  passwordField.frame.size.width, height: passwordField.frame.size.height)

    passwordBorder.borderWidth = width

    passwordField.layer.addSublayer(passwordBorder)

    passwordField.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

How would I put this code into a helper function so I could call it easily?

I am new to coding and am having trouble with helper functions on anything `UI`.   Thanks!

Comment: what type of customisation you want for button

Comment: create a function that returns button with border as you want to reuse code

Comment: You can take a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27645782/6080920

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Swift's Extensions. You could pretty easily do something like

```
extension UIButton {
      func setPasswordBorderColor(borderColor: UIColor) {
        //White Border
        let passwordBorder = CALayer()

        let width = CGFloat(5.0)

        passwordBorder.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor

        passwordBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)

        passwordBorder.borderWidth = width

        self.layer.addSublayer(passwordBorder)

        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit


// 
@IBDesignable
class CustomBorderButton: UIButton  {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            layer.masksToBounds = cornerRadius > 0
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor?.CGColor
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Without Code you can configure your button**

Select Your button then Select Identity Inspector then add

**"User Defined Runtime Attribute"**.See screen Shot for more details

Add CALayer+XibConfiguration.h & CALayer+XibConfiguration.m  in your Project

for  CALayer+XibConfiguration open this [link](https://github.com/ConventionalC/ConventionalC/tree/master/ios) & download CALayer+XibConfiguration

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways by which you can achieve this like using category, subclassing `UIButton`, or create a function in a class (may be base class inherited by all other classes.), etc.

By using function you ca do

```
func cutomizeButton(frame : CGRect, title : String) -> UIButton {

    let button : UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)

    button.frame = frame
    button.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor;
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true

    button.titleLabel?.text = title;

    //do other stuff

    return button;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In helper class make method like

```
func customiseButton(button:UIButton){
        //White Border
        let passwordBorder = CALayer()

        let width = CGFloat(5.0)

        passwordBorder.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

        passwordBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:  button.frame.size.width, height: button.frame.size.height)

        passwordBorder.borderWidth = width

        button.layer.addSublayer(passwordBorder)

        button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
```

and in ViewController call this method as

```
HelperClass().customiseButton(passwordField)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this Extension for round button:

```
extension UIButton{
          func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat){
                   let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
                   borderLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds
                   borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
                   borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
                   borderLayer.lineWidth = 10.5
                   let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                            byRoundingCorners: corners,
                            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
                   borderLayer.path = path.cgPath
                   self.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
     }
}
```